# why is Catalyst::Helper::View::TTSite deprecated?

Tags: perl, templates, deprecated, catalyst, template-toolkit

I've just started getting into Catalyst, and I've been finding it really helpful. One of my favorite things about it was TTSite in that it got me going fast and gave me something to develop with without just black text (and it required no work from me to setup). However, I've been reading in a lot of places that it's buggy, or even deprecated as mentioned [here](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial::03_MoreCatalystBasics) on the actual Catalyst tutorial. However I've found it nothing but helpful and have had no issues, so basically I'm wondering is there reason for me to be worried and not use it? And if so, does anyone know of a similar alternative that kind of gives you a base template set up to work within? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think TTSite is *officially* deprecated in terms of support .. it is still included in the [Catalyst::View::TT](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-View-TT/) distribution as of 0.39 (released 10-April 2012).  I suspect it is more a case of some developers disliking the base templates that are provided and TTSite no longer being recommended as part of the default Catalyst tutorial.

TTSite provides a very simple base that has some quirks.  For example, the context object is called Catalyst instead of c, and the use of TT's WRAPPER command can get in the way of AJAX and non-html views.

More background reading:

- [Discussion on the Catalyst-Dev mailing list regarding changing the Catalyst tutorial from TTSite to straight TT](http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/catalyst-dev/2008-May/001215.html)
- [Catalyst wiki: disabling TT wrapper for AJAX requests](http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/gettingstarted/howtos/disabling_a_tt_wrapper_for_ajax_requests)
- [A blog post on TTSite including changing Catalyst context reference to c](http://brunorc.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/catalyst-is-easy-fourth-movement/)

A modern base theme would probably start with something like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or one of the [960 Grid](http://960.gs/) HTML/CSS frameworks.  I'm not aware of an actively maintained Catalyst::View helper that would be a better replacement for TTSite, but also don't find it too onerous to drop in the latest version of Bootstrap :)